# Java - long queue of tasks can interfere with user input?

Tags: java, queue

I am writing this Queue object which performs tasks one after the other. But if I have a long list of tasks to perform, this could interfere with all bunch of stuff, am I right? Like reactions to user input for example. 
I think I should wait a millisecond before performing the next task, so the system can make other calculations if needed?
So, how do I do this in Java? In Javascript I would use setInterval, but I'm pretty new to Java.

Thanks for reading!

Comment: Why don't you execute the tasks in a background thread and *forget* the time it takes to process the elements in the queue?

Comment: Most operating systems use [preemptive scheduling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preemption_%28computing%29) nowadays.

Comment: Because I had no idea such a thing was possible. Ah I guess I need to read about threading and multi-threading then! Thank you.